# How to resize webview objects/texts depending on screensize

Tags: android, webview

I am creating an app that will be used for all screen sizes.. I have different layouts for small, normal, large, and x-large.. However, I also want my webview to adjust its sizes (text/images) depending on the size of the screen. I tried researching for viewport and values/dimens.xml but had no luck..Here is dimens.xml but I do not know how to apply it:
(This is for xlarge)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="body_padding_large"> 20dp </dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_xlarge"> 32sp </dimen>
<dimen name="speaker_image_size"> 64dp </dimen>
</resources>
```